# Stop or pause threads in python 3

Tags: multithreading, python-3.3, thread-sleep

I have a list containing x number of threads (t[ ]). I want to stop or kill or pause them indefinitely. How do I do it? If I have to use time.sleep, how do I do it, to make each thread in the list sleep?

```
def downNow(d): #A function to download a file
step = d.size//d.noOfThreads        
init= 0
for i in range(d.noOfThreads-1):
    d.thread_list.append(DownloadThread.D_thread(DownloadThread.download_file, (init, step, d, i)))
    init=step+init
    d.thread_list[i].start()
step = d.size-init
d.thread_list.append(DownloadThread.D_thread(DownloadThread.download_file, (init, step, d, d.noOfThreads-1)))
d.thread_list[d.noOfThreads-1].start()
```

d is a download object containing information like url and size etc.

The DownloadThread.download_file function is

```
def download_file(init, step, d, i):
try:
    req = Request(d.url, headers={'Range':'bytes=%s-%s'%(init,init+step)})
    d.data[i] = bytes(urlopen(req).read())
```

I want to create a function pause, to freeze the download at the current stage. So I want to know how to stop each individual thread in the d.thread_list.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you better.

Comment: I have edited the question, please see if you can help me out.